# Protobuf how to use Any type with homebrew proto message

Tags: python, grpc, proto

I'm currently building a python gRPC server that serializes tons of different proto messages into json to store them into a no-sql db. I'd like to simplify extension of this server such that we can add new types without rewriting the gRPC server and redeploying. Ideally, we would like to define a new message, put it in a proto file and update only the client. The server should expect any type at first but knows a .proto file or folder where to look for when it comes to serializing/deserializing.

I've read about the Any type and I'm exploring whether this is my way to do this. There is some documentation on it but very few examples to work with. One thing that I don't quite get is how to store/retrieve the type of an "Any" field.

- All documentation use https as protocol for the type of an Any field (e.g. type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Duration). This is also the default. How would it look like if I use the local file system? How would I store this in the proto message on the client side?
- How can I retrieve the type on the server side?
- Where can I find a similar example?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, this is only a partial answer.

I've recently begun using Any in a project and can provide some perspective. I have a similar (albeit simpler) requirement to what you outline. Enveloped message content but, in my case, clients are required to ship a  descriptor to the server and identify a specific method to help it (un)marshal etc.

I've been using Google's new Golang APIv2 and only familiar with it from Golang and Rust (not Python). The documentation is lacking but the Golang documents will hopefully help:

- [anypb](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb?tab=doc)
- [protoregistry](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry?tab=doc)

I too struggled with understanding the concept (implementation) of the global registry and so I hacked the above solution. The incoming message metadata provides sufficient context to the server that it can construct the message type and marshal the bytes into it.